# New elements added to ObservableCollection from external Page are not persisted

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, xamarin.forms.shell

I have two pages. On the first I want to see every elements from `ObservableCollection` and the second I want to add new element to `ObservableCollection`. When I give breakpoint I see that the `ObservableCollection` has new element, but when I back to the first page new element dosen't exist. What should I do?

**There is code**

```
        public ListViewFlascardViewModel()
    {
        GoToAddFlashcard = new Command(goToAddFlashcard);
        Fiszka = new ObservableCollection<Flashcard>();
        Fiszka.Add(new Flashcard {Name = "hello" });         
    }
    
    
    public Command GoToAddFlashcard { get; }
    Flashcard flashcard = new Flashcard();        

    async void goToAddFlashcard()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(View.NoweFiszki));;            
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Flashcard> Fiszka { get; set; }
}
```

**And there is second page:**

```
 class NoweFiszkiViewModel
{
    public Command SaveFlashcard { get; }
    public NoweFiszkiViewModel()
    {
       
        SaveFlashcard = new Command(save);
    }


    ListViewFlascardViewModel list = new ListViewFlascardViewModel();
   

    private async void save()
    {
        list.Fiszka.Add(new Flashcard { Name = "Bye" });            
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}
```

I try a lot of things, but nothing help. I am new in `C#` and I will be appreciated for every help.

I add whole code.

**There is view**

**ListViewFlashcard**

```
<ContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MVVM.ViewModel" 
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MVVM.Model"
x:Class="MVVM.View.ListViewFlashcard"   
x:DataType="viewmodels:ListViewFlascardViewModel"
>

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:ListViewFlascardViewModel/>        
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    
    <Button 
            Command="{Binding GoToAddFlashcard}"
            Text="Click Me"/>
    
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Fiszka}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Flashcard">
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>        
</StackLayout>
```

**NoweFiszki**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MVVM.ViewModel"
         x:Class="MVVM.View.NoweFiszki">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:NoweFiszkiViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Text="Save"
                Command="{Binding SaveFlashcard}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**And Model**

**Flashcard**

```
    public class Flashcard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**And AppShell**

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MVVM.AppShell"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM.View"
   >   
<FlyoutItem Title="Add Flashcard" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ListViewFlashcard}"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

```
    public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NoweFiszki), typeof(NoweFiszki));            
    }

}
```

It is everything what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things have to be corrected on your code:

In **NoweFiszkiViewModel** you are creating a new instance of **ListViewFlascardViewModel** every time, and adding elements on that new instance, which does not affect the instance to which **ListViewFlashcard** is actually bound.

To fix this, you will have to create a `public static ListViewFlascardViewModel` in **ListViewFlashcard.xaml.cs** and set the binding context to it, as follows

**ListViewFlashcard.xaml.cs**

```
public static ListViewFlascardViewModel vm { get; set; }

public ListViewFlashcard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new ListViewFlascardViewModel();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
            
    BindingContext = vm;
}
```

then correct **ListViewFlashcard.xaml** as follows

**ListViewFlashcard.xaml**

```xml
<!--<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:ListViewFlascardViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>-->
<StackLayout>
    <Button 
        Command="{Binding GoToAddFlashcard}"
        Text="Click Me"/>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Fiszka}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:Flashcard">
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Finally you have to correct NoweFiszkiViewModel.cs as follows, adding the new elements to the `public static` view model:

**NoweFiszkiViewModel.cs**

```cs
public Command SaveFlashcard { get; }

public NoweFiszkiViewModel()
{
    SaveFlashcard = new Command(save);
}

//ListViewFlascardViewModel list = new ListViewFlascardViewModel();

private async void save()
{
    ListViewFlashcard.vm.Fiszka.Add(new Flashcard { Name = "Bye" });
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```